# How to use Environment Variables in CI/CD Pipeline in Azure

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I am creating the CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps for .NetCore API, and I have multiple deployment stages like QA, UAT and Production. Every stages has its own setting like database connectionstrings and many other, and I have one **appsettings.json** file in which I declared these settings, so its very hard work to change **appsettings.json** file each time in deployment, so my question is that how I can use environment variables in CI/CD pipelines to avoid all this stuff,

> As I Just need to define the variables values in variables section and CD pipeline can automatically pick it from my appsetting.json file.

**appsetting.json** File

```
 "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "SubscriptionClientName": "api",
  "MessageBrokerRetryCount": 5,

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CaseDBConnectionString": "Server=db-server;Database=api_db;User ID=user;pwd =Password;"
  },

  //For Dev
  "MessageBrokerConnection": "ip",
  "MessageBrokerUserName": "john",
  "MessageBrokerPassword": "john"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a more reasonable approach would be to use application settings of you App Service, they would override values in appsettings.json\web.config

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common

this might require slight code changes on your part:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-language-dotnetcore#access-environment-variables

Comment: Or better still, integrating the application directly with a keyvault so required values are securely stored and retrieved as needed.

Comment: well, that would require more code changes ;) and a slight paradigm shift

Comment: Basically I am searching a solution to add variables in azure devops  section CD pipelines instead of change configuration in azure webapp directly.

Comment: add variables to what? key vault would be the best approach, tbh

Comment: I have followed the following URL [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common) and its works for me, but  I have some confusion is this the best possible approach to define values in Azure app services configuration section, or  we may use Azure DevOps pipeline Variable for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

We typically use the "Replace Tokens" task in our releases, and then set the variables in our release pipeline for each environment that will replace the tokens in our appsettings.json file.  Very simple to use and set up.

**UPDATE:**

In your appsettings.json file, you would do something like:

```
"Username": "#{AccountUser}#"
```

Then in your pipeline, you would go into your release and create a variable called "AccountUser".  Then you use the [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task in your release as the first step, and it will replace #{AccountUser}# in your appsettings.json file with whatever the value of the variable is.  Set different variables for each Scope (dev, stage, production or whatever you call your environments in your release) so that your appsettings.json file gets the appropriate value per environment.

[image]

Comment: could you please give me some example of 'Rplace Token Tasks' , means how  I can replace my values in appsetting.json file though this tasks

Comment: I have done my work with Two ways like from the i have followed the article "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common" and

Comment: I have done my work with 2 ways like I have followed the article"[https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common][1]" Like this will overwrite the values into the appsettings.json file.
2nd way I have removed the values into the  Azure Webapp services Configuration section and define the values into the Azure Release pipeline variables section and also define the variable group (like one group is related to QA, Prod) and in **Deploy Azure App Service** tasks section under **File Transforms & Variable Substitution Options** give the appsetting.json file name.
Thanks!

Comment: This answer is more appropriate to the question than the accepted answer - the accepted answer doesn't actually answer the original question. Just sayin'.